# A simple function to query MSSQL then close the connection for use in quick scripts

Tags: node.js, sql-server, connection-pooling

I have a script that I want to be able to schedule to run periodically, and query a DB, open a connection, execute a query, then close the connection.

Trying to make the following code work:

```
const Query = require('./query_db')
Query("select * from table").then( result => doSomethingWith(result) );
Query("select * from table2").then( result => doSomethingWith(result) );
```

Because these can resolve in any order (which is ok) I can't tell this script when to close the connection, so I want to have the query_db module responsible for opening and closing the connection per request.

The original module code was as follows:

```
const sql = require("mssql")
const config = require("./config").db

query_db = async function (sql_query) {
    try {
        pool = await sql.connect(config);
        result = await pool.request().query(sql_query);
        await sql.close()
        return result.recordset;
    } catch (err) {
        new Error(err)
    }
};

module.exports = query_db
```

This worked unless I had to execute 2 queries at one time. To remedy this, I used the ConnectionPool as follows:

```
const sql = require("mssql")
const config = require("./config").db

query_db = function (sql_query) {
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool =>{
            return pool.request().query(sql_query);
        }).then(result=> {
            sql.close();
            resolve(result.recordset);
        }).catch(err => {
            sql.close();
            reject(err)
        })
    })
};

module.exports = query_db
```

This works, but the pool stays open and the application never exits. I'd like it to exit when the active connections are closed. What's the best way to do this? Is it to put the connection in the main app and pass it to the function in the module instead of trying to create/close it with in the function?

UPDATE Resolved

Got it working as such. Much simpler as well.

```
module.exports = async function (sql_query) {
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    try {
        await pool.connect();
        let result = await pool.request().query(sql_query)
        return result.recordset;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR:", err)
    }
    finally {
        pool.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The goal is for the calling script to be a list of queries to run, and have the results sent to a messaging service (posted to a webex feed in this case)... I was hoping to keep the DB function standalone so the calling application could be a simple list of  query_db("select ... from ...").then(result => doSomethingWIth(result) )

Comment: I want the module to open the pool on the first query, handle one or more queries, then close immediately (or with a few second timeout) when there' s no more activity.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I resolved it (and updated the original post with the working code.)

Comment: Wanted to share the result. Would it be more appropriate to submit as an answer to my question rather than update it with the response?

Comment: It looks like you deleted your comment, but it most likely helped me get to the solution. I believe my initial thought was that the pool wouldn't be available with in the scope of the finally block. The solution I used was to create the pool outside of the promise chain so I could close it after the chain completed. I didn't mean to discount your suggestion to use pool.close() as that's absolutely correct, but I don't think it would have worked in the original code.